# Strange issue desired function not getting called in C

Tags: c

In our legacy product code, there is function defined as:

```
int
mkdirhier(char * path, mode_t mode, uid_t uid, gid_t gid)
{
printf("TEMP_DEBUG: Inside function mkdirhier");
<source code>
}
```

Its called as:

```
 mkdirhier( path, 0755, AdminUid, AdminGid );
```

But when we actually see is that, mkdirhier is getting called but not the one which is ours i.e. we are not getting printf message `TEMP_DEBUG: Inside function mkdirhier`

On the other hand if I change function name: `mkdirhier` to `mkdirhier_custom` and from caller code also change name to `mkdirhier_custom` I get my printfs.

We are suspecting `mkdirhier` is getting called from any system library,I searched in all the third party libraries .so, .a, .o using  command:

```
find . -name "*.a" | xargs nm -C | grep "mkdirhier"
similarly for .so , .o
```

But no such occurrences.

We are using third party libraries `libcurl`,`libevent`,`openssl` but no occurrences of `mkdirhier`.

Even I tried to run our application with `gdb` and added breakpoint at `mkdirhier`.

`gdb` mentions that breakpoint is applied to `mkdirhier`also mentions the file name in which we have definition. But during runtime execution via gdb it doesn't stop at `mkdirhier` and continues.

While on the other hand breakpoint at `mkdirhier_custom` when applied , during runtime it stops at `mkdirhier_custom`.
Seems with `mkdirhier` it gives priority to system call and we are not sure where its defined and even applying breakpoint doesnt' stops and I can not get backtrace as it does not stops in `mkdirhier`.

Also as its legacy code and we don't have privilege(not allowed) to final check-in for changing custom function name from `mkdirhier` to `mkdirhier_custom`

Please let me know how to proceed ahead as I am not getting any clue.

Comment: My guess is there's a macro with the same name, hiding the function.

Comment: Remember that when `stdout` (where `printf` is writing) is connected to an interactive terminal, then output is *line buffered*. You need a trailing newline, a full buffer, or an explicit call to `fflush(stdout)` for the output to actually be written. You don't have a newline, you can't know if the buffer becomes full, and you don't have a call to `fflush`. So there's no guarantee that the output you have is written when you think it is.

Comment: I guess that because of the nature of the problem you are unable to make a [mre]. If you were able you probably would have solved the problem already. I mention this, because I had to consciously suppress the urge to ask for one. ;-) Maybe you mention that explicitly... However, maybe you could work towards one starting from big, instead of starting from HelloWorld. Can you remove things from the system? Of course you then, for several steps, still cannot show the result here, but it might help you as a systematic approach.

Comment: Can you apply the gdb breakpoint to the line which calls the function and step into the function call to see where it ends up?

Comment: use `nm -D` for .so files. Set breakpoint at the call site sand step in. gdb should tell you which shared object you are in.

Comment: As mentioned, your function is probably being called, but you aren't noticing it because you forgot to include a newline in the `printf` string.  That's likely causing the string to be buffered rather than printed immediately, which you're misinterpreting as the function not being called.  Add the newline, and consider adding an `fflush(stdout);` call as well.  Then try again.

Comment: (a) If you call `mkdirhier` directly as the first thing in `main`, does the debug message show up? (b) After adding the `mkdirhier` call in `main` and compiling the code to assembly (with all other compiler switches the same), does the generated assembly show a call to the `mkdirhier` function? (c) If you set debug breakpoints at each call to `mkdirhier`, are they reached? If you then single-step over the `call` instruction, does execution reach your `mkdirhier` routine or some other routine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable thing is that:

```
printf("TEMP_DEBUG: Inside function mkdirhier");
```

is called, but you don't see the output, because it is being buffered by the stdio package.  When output to a terminal, the stdio library uses line buffered descriptors, which means that output is flushed only when a `\n` new line character is output.  Just put a `\n` at the end, and you'll then know actually if the function is being called or not.  If the output is printed to a file, the situation is worse, as only when a buffer is filled completely (this is around 16kb on actual systems) the data is written.

Another alternative is to make a `fflush(stdout);` just after the `printf()` call. This will enforce the buffer flush.  You can also `fprintf(stderr, ...);` that has small differences about buffering output against `stdout`.

Whatever method you use, I strongly recommend you to put a `\n` at the end of every log line, or your output will be a bit meshed :)